Are value or const& compatible signatures for std::function?
So I have a callback defined as:
struct S {
    int a{3};
};

using callback = std::function<void(S const&)>;

And want to call it with some function:
void f(callback&& cb) { cb(S{}); }

I noticed that the compiler did not care whether I specified the callback with S (value) or S const& (const reference) even though only the latter explicitly matches the signature:
int main()
{
    f([](S const& s) { std::cout << s.a << std::endl; });
    f([](S s) { s.a = 5; std::cout << s.a << std::endl; });
    return 0;
}

So my question is: Is this valid C++ or is it just some compiler extension (I use GCC 11)?
It would be nice to be able to have both so I can get a copy when I need to, but avoid it when not needed.
As an aside: How is it possible from the callside (here f) to know whether to pass by reference or copy? Or is this delegated to within the std::functions call operator?
For code example:
https://godbolt.org/z/afn6anWdv

A function accepting a const & argument can accept a temporary, so passing by value is fine - it can't modify what it is getting passed anyway.

Yes, but is the above legal / portable C++? When passing by value, the std::functions parameter signature does not match the one expected by f.

Here's your mental model for what's happening: imagine std::function has this template<typename... Ts> void operator()(Ts&&... ts) { call(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); } where call is your lambda.

@PasserBy, In this case, right? In the general case it must have auto return type?

It's fine. A const & can bind to a temporary and the compiler is allowed to make 1 implicit conversion. There's nothing wrong with passing an object by value or a temporary object to a function accepting a const &.

Roughly correct, but not auto, just whatever you specified.

@JesperJuhl, I'm not talking about what's passed into the callback, I'm talking about the callback itself being passed into f

std::function<F> doesn't require that the callable it wraps exactly match the signature of F. It only requires that it be invocable with arguments that are passed to F. For example, if you have void CallMe(int), then std::function<void(long)>{CallMe}(42L) works, for the same reason that void Wrapper(long l) { CallMe(l); } works.

@IgorTandetnik, Thanks - this was what I was looking for. Will you write it up as an answer so I can accept it?

If S is copy-constructible, function<void (S const&)> can  hold a void (S) too; but the result is pass by value of the parameter( f(s) creates a copy of s).

Related (same principle, different setup): std::function type cheking correct? FWIW: My search was for [c++] std::function signature
